# Как обновить Python до 3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x

На данный момент установлена версия Python 3.8, хочу обновиться до новой версии 3.9. В cmd не нашел никаких команд по типу python --upgrade. Как я могу обновиться до новой версии без переустановки?

Comment: Никак, только переустановка

Comment: Я бы не торопился это делать на вашем месте)